# "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous." when using scipy.integrate.dblquad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to perform a double integration on this function

```py
def prob(x,y):
    ch = np.sqrt((3-y)**2 + x**2)
    hb = np.sqrt((4-x)**2 + y**2)
    if np.isclose(4 * y, 12 - 3 * x):
        # Without the if statement, any x, y values that satisfy the condition will return nan
        return 0.5
    else:
        return (np.arccos((ch**2 + hb**2 - 25) / (2 * ch * hb)))/(2*np.pi)
```

[Contour plot of the function](http://prntscr.com/o0eb14)

```py
from scipy import integrate as integ
integ.dblquad(prob(x,y), 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
```

However I got this error message pointing at the if statement

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Trivially, if i use **math.isclose** instead of **np.isclose** in the if statement,  I get this error message pointing to the same statement

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

To my understanding, boolean array has something to do with these errors but checking everything including the if statement yields a scalar boolean.

So are there any way around this?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a typographical error.

From the edit I made it looks like you were calling:

```
integ.dblquad(prob(x, y), 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
```

When in fact you should be calling:

```
integ.dblquad(prob, 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
```

I believe you likely have and array `x` and array `y` that are causing the error when calling `dblquad` the first way.

E.g.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([3,4,5])
integ.dblquad(prob(x, y), 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

integ.dblquad(prob, 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
(4.42854383700761, 1.8525461432365937e-08)
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. Please do not edit the code in the question, especially in a way that invalidates the entire question. You can always vote to close as a typo.

Comment: Oh, I made a high schooler mistake and i didnt know. thanks for pointing out. I forgot it should be prob without (x,y)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the errors you get are sufficiently helpful in terms of diagnostic. The problem is that [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) will return an array of booleans, and trying to coerce such an array into a single value (which the `if` clause does) raises an error. (1)

How to fix it is more dependent on what you want to achieve. Assuming that `prob(x,y)` should return a numpy array of the same dimensions as x/y, where values are replaced by 0.5 at locations where the condition is true, you can use:

```
output = (np.arccos((ch**2 + hb**2 - 25) / (2 * ch * hb)))/(2*np.pi)
output[np.isclose(4 * y, 12 - 3 * x)] = .5
return output
```

Notice that this may not be the best way to solve your actual problem. It often makes more sense to keep NaN in positions where the calculation fails (that's what NaNs are for). If you want to replace NaNs by 0.5, you might be better off testing for NaN rather than by your math condition:

```
output = (np.arccos((ch**2 + hb**2 - 25) / (2 * ch * hb)))/(2*np.pi)
output[np.isnan(output)] = .5
return output
```

(1) One could argue that any non-empty array should evaluate to `True` similarly to what lists do in non-numpy Python, and regardless of values (i.e. `np.asarray([False])` evaluates as `True`). I for one am happy that numpy will raise an exception rather than try to guess what I want in that situation (which could be `all`, `any`, `len(array)>0`, or as here element-wise operation that needs to be rewritten).

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but the real issue is that @Grrr modified the code in the question to make it unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you need to provide full traceback and calling specification.  And you need to call `dblquad` correctly.

===

What are `x,y` when you call with

```
integ.dblquad(prob(x,y), 0, 4, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 3)
```

Depnding on those 2 variables, the error might be rising before `dblquad` is even called.

The first argument to `dblquad` is supposed to be a function, not an array.  Using `prob` instead of `prob(x,y)` might work.

Given 2 scalars `prob` works:

```
In [674]: prob(1,2)                                                                                    
Out[674]: 0.4685835209054995
```

Given two arrays we get the ambiguity error:

```
In [675]: prob(np.arange(3),np.arange(1,4))                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-675-4b16a88f567e> in <module>
----> 1 prob(np.arange(3),np.arange(1,4))

<ipython-input-673-e31785dd54a5> in prob(x, y)
      2     ch = np.sqrt((3-y)**2 + x**2)
      3     hb = np.sqrt((4-x)**2 + y**2)
----> 4     if np.isclose(4 * y, 12 - 3 * x):
      5         # Without the if statement, any x, y values that satisfy the condition will return nan
      6         return 0.5

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And the full traceback (which you should have given us) shows the problem is with the `isclose` call:

```
In [676]: np.isclose(np.arange(3),np.arange(1,4))                                                      
Out[676]: array([False, False, False])
```

It produces a boolean array, which can't be used in an `if` clause.

Using `math.isclose` raises error because `math` functions only accept scalars.  They don't work with arrays (multivalued ones).

Using `dblquad` correctly, it works:

```
In [678]: integ.dblquad(prob, 0,4,lambda x:0, lambda x:3)                                              
Out[678]: (4.42854383700761, 1.8525461432365937e-08)
```

`dblquad` passes scalar values to your function, so the use of `isclose` (either numpy or math) isn't problem

Using `math` functions with scalar inputs is faster:

```
def probm(x,y):
    ch = math.sqrt((3-y)**2 + x**2)
    hb = math.sqrt((4-x)**2 + y**2)
    if math.isclose(4 * y, 12 - 3 * x):
        # Without the if statement, any x, y values that satisfy the condition will return nan
        return 0.5
    else:
        return (math.acos((ch**2 + hb**2 - 25) / (2 * ch * hb)))/(2*math.pi)

In [683]: integ.dblquad(probm, 0,4,lambda x:0, lambda x:3)                                             
Out[683]: (4.428543836134556, 1.8890715880459652e-08)
```

much faster:

```
In [685]: timeit integ.dblquad(prob, 0,4,lambda x:0, lambda x:3)                                       
11.7 s ± 24.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [686]: timeit integ.dblquad(probm, 0,4,lambda x:0, lambda x:3)                                      
272 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```